# Trying to delete four rows out of 5 in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

So far I have

```
Sub Delete_Alternate_Rows_Excel()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Dim rw As Range
Dim RowCount As Integer


Set sh = ActiveSheet
For Each rw In sh.Rows
  If rw.RowIndex Mod 5 <> 0 Then
  End If
  
  rw.EntireRow.Delete
  

Next rw

End Sub
```

But i am getting a Run time error. Does anyone know what the problem is here

Answer (score 0):

You have a few problems here.

`Range.RowIndex` is not a thing, that will cause an error.

`rw.EntireRow.Delete` is outside the `IF` so it will always be executed.

Lastly, don't delete in a loop, it is very resource intensive and rows will shift up, causing you to skip ones you want to delete or delete ones you want saved.

This should do what you are looking for:

```
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim delrange As Range
    With ActiveSheet 'You may want to use an actual sheet name/codename
        lr = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For i = 2 To lr 'I'm assuming you have headers and want to go through the entire sheet
            If i Mod 5 <> 0 Then
                If delrange Is Nothing Then
                    Set delrange = .Rows(i)
                Else
                    Set delrange = Union(delrange, .Rows(i))
                End If
            End If
        Next i
        delrange.Delete
    End With
```